# What is a good system for adding retina images using LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

I would like to add retina images to a site more efficiently using LESS.

Here is a potential solution I'm looking at:

```
@2x: ~"only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)",
     ~"only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi)";

.logo {
   background: url(/images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;

  @media @2x {
    .logo {
       background-image: url(/images/logo@2x.png);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so what exactly is your question?  does the solution you just included cause a problem in any way?

Comment: The question is very clear. Looking for improvements on the code example.